# Why files have opposite line terminators on different PCs?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, linebreaks

I tried asking about this on stackoverflow but was kind of pointed here.

Here's what's going on:

1. We generate a file, which contains CRLF line breaks (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04). It's an .scv file, generated via php script using PhpOffice, line breaks are set as "\r\n". To clarify, it isn't necessary being open on Ubuntu.
2. We send that file to another person, on other PC (who uses Windows). They claim to recieve file with CRLF+CR line breaks
3. They send us another file, which (as they say) cointains CRLF. But when I open it or just try to see encoding, it contains CRLF+CR.

Discussing this led us nowhere so far. I do know that LF is new line in Ubuntu and CRLF is new line in Windows. But I don't understand why would CRLF be switched out with CRLFCR (and vice versa). And more importantly, how can it be resolved? We don't edit this file by any text editor before sending it, we don't even open it.

Comment: Are you sure it's CRLF+CR and not CR+CRLF? The latter would be much easier to produce accidentally. What method are you using the send file? Have you tried checking the line endings _on the original system_ for both cases you described?

Comment: About recieved file - I was sure it's CRLF+CR because that's what terminal command returns to me ("CRLF, CR line terminators"), but now I opened file in Notepad++ and it's indeed CR+CRLF. We send files through mail and messangers, in zip archives in both cases. Before I send the file, I check encoding via terminal + I did check it in text editors after we found out about problem. As for received file - I have to rely on screenshots and words of the other side

Comment: It's zipped? Like FTP, some zip/unzip programs have the ability to "correct" line endings. What are you using?

Comment: I've been using GUI zip. Just tried to send unzipped file, looks like it worked, thank you!
I'll wait a little for full confirmation and close the question

Comment: In addition to that, what zip program is the recipient using? (It might be interesting to see the output of `zipinfo -v thearchive.zip`, for both the archive you sent and the archive you received.)

Comment: Also, in this situation, the best way to "close" the question is by posting your own full answer with details of what you discovered, rather than using the 'Close' function.

Comment: I, unfortunatelly, have to talk to recipient via couple another people, so I can't ask them about what they use (not now anyway, after question seems to be resolved)

Comment: And thank you for a tip, I wrote an answer and will close it after 21 hours pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, looks like zipping the files caused problems. Plus, I've been mistaken and line breaks were CR+CRLF, not CRLF+CR. File sent witout archive worked like a charm

Comment: Note `file sent without archive` may also get altered, depending on how you send it. This is a relatively common problem with FTP. Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1091022/432690). It's relevant you had a file with `\r\n` line endings on Linux/Unix where `\n` is expected. Some tools try to be smart and replace every `\n` with `\r\n` when transferring text files from Linux/Unix to Windows.  This comment is to indicate the problem is not restricted to zipped files.