# Is it possible that FTP makes any bit error?

Tags: ftp, sftp, tcp

I have been thinking so far that FTP deosn't cause any bit errors while transferring files. But recently, I met a problem that the files I sent through FTP between my two servers are sometimes different. They makes different hash values with MD5 checksum algorithm. So I searched about FTP bit errors, I found some articles that TCP uses low level error detection so FTP also can makes bit errors.

Then, how much probability that FTP causes any bit error when transferring compressed files(.gz) which size is abount 10MB? And can I resolve this problem with SFTP instead of FTP? If not, how can I handle this?

> **My Environment**
>
> Source: WinSCP for FTP Client (Windows Server 2012 R2)
>
> Dest: FileZilla for FTP Server (Windows Server 2012 R2)

Edit) In my case, the cause may not be FTP transmission error. I just wonder that the reason is FTP or others.

Comment: Ah, I see your edit. 
It would pay to check for underlying disk i/o errors. And the NT FS. And though it *shouldn't* matter, I would use filezilla on src and dest. (I have an aversion to software that starts with "win...")

Comment: A network protocol cannot make a "*bit error*".  Network protocols run on top of a physical medium that is not 100% reliable.  That is the source of possible "*bit errors*".  Protocols vary in their capabilities to deal with any errors during transfers, e.g. the classic comparison between (unreliable) UDP versus (reliable) TCP.  "*And can I resolve this problem with SFTP instead of FTP?*" -- You seem to be confusing security with reliablity.

Comment: Make sure you transfer in binary, not in text mode. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1098338/432690) for some insight. Files that are not text get corrupted when transferred in text mode. This applies to FTP; SFTP always transfers as-is.

Comment: @sawdust I have found an [article](https://help.globalscape.com/help/archive/cuteftp8/Verifying_integrity_of_transferred_files.htm) that SFTP uses checksum(MD5 or SHA) for integrity checking. Is this different from my case?

Comment: Suggest you follow @KamilMaciorowski 's advice.

Comment: SFTP does not do checksum verification of the files. But as it is an encrypted complex protocol, if "bit error" occurs while transferring data over the network, the receiver will fail to decode the protocol packet and you will know that something went wrong. See also [How to perform checksums during a SFTP file transfer for data integrity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30056566/850848) This is not the case with plain unencrypted FTP.

Comment: did you do `ftp> bin` ?   (manual mode) or ensure your (gui) ftp client uses binary mode?

Comment: @Hannu I used WinSCP script with automatic mode, but I will specify to use binary mode according to above comments.

Answer (score 0):

The universe causes bit-flips more frequently than you might believe. That's one reason that checksumming and error detection are accounted for in things like tftp. I wouldn't jump to blaming the protocol.

> Is it possible that FTP makes any bit error?

Yes, but not the most likely suspect IMO.

> And can I resolve this problem with SFTP instead of FTP? If not, how can I handle this?

Top of my list would be `rsync`, though it could be handled over `ssh` with `cp`/`rcp` (which would seem to be comparable to sftp.)