# 'find' command giving error in script but not in command line

Tags: linux, shell-script, tcsh

I have a simple file as below.
When I key-in each command in the shell, it works but when I compile them in a script, it doesnt - produces error - no file or directories found , shown below

I cant seem to figure out why this is

```sh
#!/bin/tcsh -f
set curdir = `pwd`
echo $curdir
set default = `find $curdir -name "*.metadb" `
echo $default
exit
```

screen shot in command line
[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message `…/test\r': No such file or directory` makes me suspect that *at least* the line

```
set curdir = `pwd`
```

in your script contains a trailing carriage return character. See this similar question: [Why am I getting `line 1: $' :\r': command not found`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/391223/108618)

When typing by hand, you naturally don't type this character*.

The character is as wrong as `X` would be in

```
set curdir = `pwd`X
```

Use `dos2unix thescript` to fix the script. There are more methods under the linked question. For completeness, here's a portable method:

```
tr -d '\r' <thescript >script.new && mv script.new thescript
```

(This will remove all carriage returns from *anywhere* in the script.)

In the future do not let Windows line endings contaminate your scripts. If you edit your scripts in some Windows text editor, make sure it uses [`\n` specific to Unix, not `\r\n` specific to Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation). In some circumstances transferring a file via FTP may add carriage return characters (an example and insight: [here](https://superuser.com/a/1098338/432690)).

---

*Actually probably you do. Your <kbd>Enter</kbd> probably sends `\r`, but ultimately it's interpreted by the shell as "execute the command line" anyway. In effect you don't type `\r` into the command line. OTOH `\r` in your script is not interpreted like this. In a script only `\n` terminates a line.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, yes carriage return is indeed the issue. The issue is now resoved. thanks for highlighting that. I wrote the code on notepad++ in windows env. Just figured out I can switch it to unix env.