# Some files have '?' at the end of the file name, and I need to find such files

Tags: linux, windows, bash

I don't have any idea how these files came about to be, but here's what it looks like with `ls -lh`:

```
total 8.1G
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.6G Apr 13  2022 test_some_data_S6_R2.fastq.gz?
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.5G Apr 13  2022 test_some_data_S6_R1.fastq.gz
```

When I use ls to get the file name to auto-complete, it looks like this -

```
ls /path/to/file/test_some_data_S6_R2.fastq.gz^M
```

`^M` is supposed to be carrier return in DOS, so my best guess, someone might have copied the name from a Windows system and used that for naming the file. There are plenty of methods to replace `^M` in the contents of the file, but in my case I want to find files with `^M` in its name.

I tried `find /path/with/files/ -iname "^M"`, but no luck. I tried to escape with `\`, but still no dice. I'm SSHing into a [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) machine using MobaXTerm, so I tried Windows shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, but it hides the current working window, and doesn't insert `^M`.

Comment: Your `find` filter does not have a wildcard, so it cannot work. No idea if it’ll work with a wildcard though.

Comment: "no idea how these files came to be" – You created or edited a shell script in a text editor that used line endings specific to DOS/Windows, i.e. `\r\n` aka `CRLF` This `\r` in some circumstances is shown as `^M` or denoted as `CR` (these are different representations of the same single-byte character). When reading a script Bash treats sole `\n` as line terminator, almost any \*nix tool does. If there is `\r` just before, it gets interpreted as any other character. E.g. `touch /path/to/file\r` will create a file with the name that can be represented as `file\r` or `file^M`. (contn'd)

Comment: (contn'd) Use `dos2unix` or *don't* use text editors that use `CRLF` in the first place.

Comment: Another possibility is FTP that translated `LF` to `CRLF`. If you happen to transfer your scripts via FTP(S) then compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1098338/432690). Windows-centric text editor is a more probable cause though.

Comment: I did some snooping around, and I think the output filename was copied over from Notepad or something similar (From a windows machine sshing into linux server using MobaXTerm). I guess you're on the money with that one! @KamilMaciorowski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, you can use `$'\r'` to insert the `^M` control character.

```
find /path/with/files -name '*'$'\r'
```

- `iname` is not needed as the glob expression doesn't contain any letters
- an asterisk must be included to match the name before the `^M`

I was even able to enter `^M` directly to a bash command line by the combination of <kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl + m</kbd>. The actual key might depend on `bind` and its assignment of `quoted-insert`.

```
find /path/with/files -name '*^M'
```

Comment: I have some doubt with the quoting, does the quote before * end after \r? would this be equivalent? ```"*'$'\r"```

Comment: @KarthikNair: No. There are two things, `'*'` and `$'\r'`. You could have tested it with `find`, your expressions doesn't find the files while the original one does.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small variation on the method that [@choroba posted in their answer](https://superuser.com/a/1767070/167207).

In a text editor create a small script (called myscript here) that looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*^M" -print0 | xargs -0 ls
```

The only trick here is that you need to insert the character `^M` literally, and there are special tricks for doing so depending on the text editor. In vi or vim it is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>. In emacs it is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>. Use what ever is needed.

Then make the script executable:

```
chmod 755 myscript
```

Then execute the script `./myscript`. It should just list the files ending with the `^M` character. If it does what you want change the `xargs -0 ls` to `xargs -0 rm -f` and execute the script again to remove the files